# Java - Insert String into another String after string pattern?

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a specific string into another (or create a new one) after a certain string pattern inside the original String.

For example, given this string,

```
"&2This is the &6String&f."
```

How would I insert "&l" after all "&x" strings, such that it returns,

```
"&2&lThis is the &6&lString&f&l."
```

I tried the following using positive look-behind Regex, but it returned an empty String and I'm not sure why. The "message" variable is passed into the method.

```
    String[] segments = message.split("(?<=&.)");

    String newMessage = "";

    for (String s : segments){
        s.concat("&l");
        newMessage.concat(s);
    }

    System.out.print(newMessage);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
message.replaceAll("(&.)", "$1&l")
```

- `(&.)` finds pattern where an ampersand (`&`) is followed by anything. (`&x` as you've written).
- `$1&l` says *replace the captured group by the captured group itself followed by `&l`*.

**code**

```
String message = "&2This is the &6String&f.";
String newMessage = message.replaceAll("(&.)", "$1&l"); 
System.out.println(newMessage);
```

**result**

```
&2&lThis is the &6&lString&f&l.
```

Comment: I'm probably doing something wrong, but that didn't work for me. It just returned the original string. I tried:
`String newMessage = message.replaceAll("(&.)", "$1&l");`  
`System.out.print(newMessage);`

Comment: @BlackBeltPanda I've compiled this code. You can take a look at it here : [Java - Insert String into another String after string pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMTEt6TmxPeS0zODQ) Are you sure you're not printing `message` instead of `newMessage`?

Comment: Yes, I tried printing both to compare them and they look the same. It outputs: `Original Message: &b[&3Obsidian&aAuctions&b] &5&cAttention, an auction is beginning!`  
`New Message: &b[&3Obsidian&aAuctions&b] &5&cAttention, an auction is beginning!`

It's like it doesn't want to match the regex.

Comment: @BlackBeltPanda can you please edit your question and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually just figured it out. Another method was changing the "&" to a "§" so I modified the regex to look for "(§.)" and replace with "$1§l". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be similar to the one above. It just this way would be reusable and customizable in many circumstances.

```
public class libZ
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String a = "&2This is the &6String&f.";
        String b = patternAdd(a, "(&.)", "&l");
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    public static String patternAdd(String input, String pattern, String addafter)
    {
        String output = input.replaceAll(pattern, "$1".concat(addafter));
        return output;
    }
}
```